# Aggregate pipeline Match -> Lookup -> Unwind -> Match issue

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am puzzled as to why the code below doesn't work. Can anyone explain, please?
For some context: My goal is to get the score associated with an answer option for a survey database where answers are stored in a separate collection from the questions. The questions collection contains an array of answer options, and these answer options have a score.

Running this query:

```
db.answers.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        userId: "abc",
        questionId: ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4")
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "questions",
        localField: "questionId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "question"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$question"
},
{
    $unwind: "$question.options"
},
{
    $unwind: "$answers"
}
])
```

I get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598e588e0c5e24452c9ee769"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "questionId" : ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4"),
    "answers" : {
        "id" : 20
    },
    "question" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4"),
        "options" : {
            "id" : 10,
            "score" : "12"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598e588e0c5e24452c9ee769"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "questionId" : ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4"),
    "answers" : {
        "id" : 20
    },
    "question" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4"),
        "options" : {
            "id" : 20,
            "score" : "4"
        }
    }
}
```

All great. If I now add to the original query a match that's supposed to find the answer option having the same id as the answer (e.g. `questions.options.id == answers.id`), things don't work as I would expect.

The final pipeline is:

```
db.answers.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        userId: "abc",
        questionId: ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4")
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "questions",
        localField: "questionId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "question"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$question"
},
{
    $unwind: "$question.options"
},
{
    $unwind: "$answers"
},
{
    $match: {
        "question.options.id": "$answers.id"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        score: "$question.options.score"
    }
}
])
```

This returns an empty result. But if I change the RHS of the `$match` from `"$answers.id"` to `20`, it returns the expected `score: 4`. I tried everything I could think of, but couldn't get it to work and can't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following pipeline:

```
{
    $match: {
        userId: "abc",
        questionId: ObjectId("598be01d4efd70a81c1c5ad4")
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "questions",
        localField: "questionId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "question"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$question"
},
{
    $unwind: "$question.options"
},
{
    $unwind: "$answers"
},
{
    $addFields: {
        areEqual: { $eq: [ "$question.options.id", "$answers.id" ] }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        areEqual: true
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        score: "$question.options.score"
    }
}
```

I think the reason it didn't work with a direct match is the fact that `questions.options.id` doesn't actually reference the intended field... I needed to use `$questions.options.id` which wouldn't work as a LHS of a `$match`, hence the need to add an extra helper attribute.